# CSS Works Everywhere Except In Safari

Tags: css, safari

I am using css to animate a div that contains text. The animation works as expected in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, but not in Safari. The css 1) centers the div, 2) grows the font size from 0 to 200px while simultaneously 3) rotating the div 360deg around the Y axis.

I've "decorated" the presentation so as to make it easier to see what is happening: 1) a small, red square in the center of the window, and 2) a red border around the div.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Text Animation</title>
        <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myText">Hello World!</div>

        <div id="decoration" style="width:10px; height:10px; background-color:red; position: fixed; top:50%; left:50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        /* Initiating the animation via javascript makes it easier to try things */

        window.onload = function() { setTimeout(initiateAnimation, 200) }

        function initiateAnimation() {
            let rotate = "rotateText 2s linear 0s 1 normal none running"
            let grow = "growText 2s linear 0s 1 normal forwards running"

            let myText = jQuery("#myText")

            myText.css("animation", rotate + ", " + grow)

            //myText.css("animation", grow)

            //myText.css("width", 300)
            //myText.css("height", 100)
            //myText.css("animation", rotate)
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
@keyframes growText {
    from { font-size: 0px; }
    to { font-size: 100px; }
}

@keyframes rotateText {
    from { transform: rotateY(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%); }
    to { transform: rotateY(360deg) translate(-50%, -50%); }
}


#myText {
    /* Center the div */
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* Put the axis of rotation back to the center of the div (ie. compensate for the translation) */
    transform-origin: left top;

    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;

    font-size: 0px;

    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Here it is running correctly in Chrome:

[image: Running in Chrome]

Here it is running errantly in Safari:

[image: Running in Safari]

Note that the axis of rotation is on the left hand edge of the div. So, Safari is honoring the value of the transform-origin. But, Safari is not honoring the translate 50% 50% transform. It is as though Safari does not allow multiple properties to be modified in a keyframe.

You can see it in a browser using this [link](https://robertvaessen.com/animated-text/).

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Update 1**: If, in Safari, I run only one of the keyframe animations (either rotateText or growText) then it works as desired - everything is properly centered.

Comment: please tell me what your version of safari

Comment: Hi @Max. Safari version is 13.1.3

Comment: ok let's try prefix

Comment: Thank you for engaging, Max. I do not understand what you mean by "let's try prefix". FYI - I updated the question with additional information - see Update 1.

Comment: I mean  `-webkit-`prefix ex: `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to        `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) `

Comment: I added the webkit prefix to the transform property in the rotateText keyframe. Safari's behavior was unchanged.

Comment: Not that its of any help in the solution, as you would suspect (since they use the same engine), it also fails on any browser (well, at least firefox, chrome and safari) on iOS devices.

Comment: Yeah @wordragon, it does. And, I suppose all webkits are not created equal since Chrome uses it but then behaves differently from Safari.